# Event call multiple time after ajax replace element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an problem with Jquery event. Jquery Event was call multiple time after I replace that element with another element but same type and same id.

```js
// 1. ajax call success and replace my block
// 2. This is my event that I want it happen. 

$(document).on("click", ".polaroid button.addImage", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // trigger browse file to upload
    $(event.target).closest("div.polaroid").find("input[type=file]").trigger("click");
});
```

This code was used to resold event was call after AJAX success. So, why is `button.addImage` with event `click` called many times at the same time AJAX is called?
This is html:

```html
<div class="col-md-3 polaroid">
 <img src="images/ingredient/default_img.png" title="Main image" />
 <input type="file" name="file-image" style="display:none"/>
 <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add" class="btn addImage"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus icon-plus"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you call this line multiple times? You should only be calling this once. If you can not call it just once, than you need to unbind it.

Comment: Just 1 time. I checked.

Comment: Probably loading this script again

Comment: If you post your html as well, we might be able to help you avoid the double click issue in the first place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely are loading this script again or calling a function that adds this event handler again

The best fix is to find where this event handler is being called again.

A workaround would be to namespace the event and always remove the event handler using `off()` before adding it again

```
$(document)
   .off('click.polaroid')
   .on("click.polaroid", ".polaroid button.addImage", function(event) {
       // other code
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

use one()

`$(document).one("click", ".polaroid button.addImage", function(event) {`

Comment: Unfortunately if you call this again...it will add another `one()` and each will be called once

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I found answer. that is use "off" before "on", like this:
I update the answer of Mr.charlietfl.

```js
$(document)
   .off('click',".polaroid button.addImage")
   .on("click", ".polaroid button.addImage", function(event) {
       event.PreventDefault();
       // other code
   });
```